# JS How to getElementById on an HTML snippet

Tags: javascript, ajax, getelementbyid

I am loading a piece of html via ajax. Once the load is complete i would like to search the response for a div of a certain id. Basically, I would like to do a `response.getElementById`.

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: @rekire Right now using a jQuery.get method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$.get({
    url: url, 
    success: function(response) {
        result = $(response).find("#result");
        if (result) {
           // found
        } else {
           //not found
        }
    }
});
```

this uses [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to search for the `id` (`#`) of `result` in the `response`

Comment: Yes thanks, even though i am using jquery in that exemple i was hopping to find a non Jquery way as this code might be proted to a different library.

Comment: @silkAdmin the source for `find()` is here -> http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.find

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the load() method via jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#container_id').load('my_file.html #id_of_div');
});
```

More documentation: [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the aja(x) request. If you load XML, you can use the `getElementById` method of the `xhr.responseXML` document directly.

If not, you will have to parse the HTML snippet. This could be done with a DOMParser, the innerHTML of a element or with your favourite library's parser function.

Answer (score 0):

U can add it the html response as a div or frame, and set it invisible for a while. then u can use normal getElementById. Faster way is by using jQuery.

--jQuery--
Leave an opened `<div id=AjaxResponse> </div>`
then on success add `$("#AjaxResponse").html(data)`
then u can use normal `getElementById()` or `$("#AjaxResponse#myId")`
But dont forget to set invisible, or enabled="false" the above div